# Wordpress admin is blank

Tags: php, wordpress

Previously, the site was working fine up until a couple of days ago (there was no changes to the site within these few days). When I go to /wp-admin I see the login form, however it's whenever I try to enter ***any*** details, that it redirects me to wp-login.php with a blank screen. I have already tried the following:

- Renaming the plugins folder to disable all plugins
- Renaming the themes folder to disable any problematic themes
- Enabling WP_DEBUG in the config to show any errors on wp-login.php, however none found.

I'm stumped. I've been trying to fix this for hours but I have no clue on the issue.

Comment: Any errors in your log? Does the page redirect on entering details or on submitting the form?

Comment: @NathanielFord Ford None at all. It goes from wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fhealthylifestylesadvice.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1 to just wp-login.php with a blank screen.

Comment: Again, on form submit or when you are entering information. In other words, is a call being made to the back end (php) or is your javascript in the browser doing something unexpected?

Comment: Also, do you have a `www` in your url, or not? Sometimes admin apps will be configured to only accept credentials from fully qualified uris.

Comment: There's nothing in the console to show that javascript is doing anything unexpected. Not sure how to check whether PHP is being called. No, there's no www. in the URL

Comment: Does it redirect **on form submit** or **before** form submit? You should also be able to check your access logs to see if the back end is receiving the login request.

Comment: On form submit, no matter whether the details are correct or not.

Comment: I've experienced an issue like this before, I did everything you have mentioned and it didn't fix. The only thing the issue was fixed, is when I went to my functions.php clear/deleted all spaces before the php ending tag then the issue was fixed.